# While Creating Tab Layout getting compile time Error

Tags: android, android-layout

We are trying to implementing Tab Layout in android. I have take the refernce of the following link.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

I am getting compile time error in the following line :

**TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();**

Can any one please help me why it is giving error **getTabHost()** is predefined android method but still i am getting compile time error on this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to extend TabActivity in your activity class.